# cosmos db pydocumentdb empty set from valid queries

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb

I have ~450 (and growing) JSON documents stored in Azure CosmosDB that I need to query from a python script. The query "select * from c" returns records every time, but doesn't return all of them [edit: the "pagesize"=-1 option solved that issue, but eventually pulling every record will be an issue]. So, I would like to use more complex queries to ensure that I get all of the records, or just the records I don't already have.

None of the slightly more complex queries that I submit will return anything but an empty set. I've tried various permutations of "select c.*columnname* from c" and "select * from c where c.createddate > *priorhighwatermarkdate*".

I've checked the syntax of my queries via the Data Explorer in the Azure Portal, and they all return the appropriate recordset by that method. They will not, however, return a recordset through pydocumentdb.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post your python code and sample documents so that i could find the key of issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can't post customer data as sample, so I'll have to come up with synthetic data as an example. Should have time soon.

Comment: Please provide at least code and mock documents.